# Как использовать библиотеку JSON Patch в Spring REST?

Tags: json, spring, rest

Как я понимаю метод PATCH в Spring REST должен обновлять только часть данных обьекта. Нашёл библиотеку json-patch, но не могу разобраться как её правильно применить в своём приложении (https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-patch). Может есть альтернативные варианты, что то получше или с более понятным описанием ? Буду благодарен за наводку.

Comment: Там же есть примеры использования прям на странице репозитория. Чтобы понять как тебе её использовать, надо сначала понять зачем ты её хочешь использовать? Какую задачу пытаешься решить?  И что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Метод PATCH служит для редактирования обьекта, вот и хочу это реализовать. Я не пойму что за ObjectMapper, JsonPatch, что нужно предеавать в метод patch? (знаю что в json-е к серверу будет содержаться специальный ключ со значением, по которым библиотека на сервере поймёт какие данные нужно изменить у обьекта)

Comment: А как же Вы собираетесь реализовывать что-то, не понимая как это что-то работает? Попробуйте для начала разобраться с Jackson (это библиотека для работы с JSON, а этот самый json-patch сделан, как модуль к Jackson). Вообще, если я правильно помню рекомендации RESTful, то для обновления ресурса можно использовать HTTP-метод PUT. Из того, что я увидел в документации к json-patch он просто умеет понимать какие поля в объекте изменились и поменять их в исходном объекте. JsonMapper это класс из библиотеки Jackson, предоставляющий API для маппинга JSON в POJO и обратно.